# What is the proper way to comment code in Python?

Tags: python, comments

I was reading PEP8 and some questions on Stack Overflow, but I was wondering about spaces between comments:

Let’s say I have this code:

```
class MyBrowser(QWebPage):
    ''' Settings for the browser.'''

    def __init__(self):
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        # Specifies whether images are automatically loaded in web pages.
        self.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, True)

    def userAgentForUrl(self, url):
        ''' Returns a User Agent that will be seen by the website. '''
        return "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1295.0 Safari/537.15"
```

What is the most Pythonic way of putting blank lines between comments and the actual code? I want to show my program to some experts. And want my code to look more professional.

Comment: i think your current spacing is fine ... also what constitutes experts?

Comment: By experts, I mean hiring manager in some company

Comment: they may not be experts.... often times employers are willing to mold you into what they want... what they want to see is that you have a grasp on python concepts and principals ... and that you are aware of some of the differences between compiled vs Interpreted etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know if this represents the "community standard" but here are [Google's Python style guides](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments) (as they relate to comments).  Specifically classes:

```
class SampleClass(object):
    """Summary of class here.

    Longer class information....
    Longer class information....

    Attributes:
        likes_spam: A boolean indicating if we like SPAM or not.
        eggs: An integer count of the eggs we have laid.
    """

    def __init__(self, likes_spam=False):
        """Inits SampleClass with blah."""
        self.likes_spam = likes_spam
        self.eggs = 0

    def public_method(self):
        """Performs operation blah."""
```

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, look at the standard library for a model.

Here's an excerpt from the *timeit* module (written by Guido van Rossum himself):

```
def print_exc(self, file=None):
    """Helper to print a traceback from the timed code.

    Typical use:

        t = Timer(...)       # outside the try/except
        try:
            t.timeit(...)    # or t.repeat(...)
        except:
            t.print_exc()

    The advantage over the standard traceback is that source lines
    in the compiled template will be displayed.

    The optional file argument directs where the traceback is
    sent; it defaults to sys.stderr.
    """
    import linecache, traceback
    if self.src is not None:
        linecache.cache[dummy_src_name] = (len(self.src),
                                           None,
                                           self.src.split("\n"),
                                           dummy_src_name)
    # else the source is already stored somewhere else

    traceback.print_exc(file=file)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Zen of Python: "Readability counts." Whatever **your team** finds to be most readable is what I would do.

Comment: generally ,however sometimes its what the python populace(as opposed to you the individual) finds more readable  (I gave you +1 though since in general this is true)

Comment: I often find my code less readable without comments, since I already know what it does, but I feel this doesn't mean I shouldn't include comments.

Comment: I don't agree that what *you* prefer is best. I've worked with people who followed weird standards (three space indentation, for example). They loved their code. No one else in the group could stand to look at it.

Comment: TBH I rarely include comments in my python ... I use self documenting variable/function names and that is often sufficient ... that said i probably would not showcase my commentless code ..

Comment: Possibly...but how many of us **actually** have code that the python community at large has seen/will **ever** see? If I can read it and my coworkers aren't griping at me I find that to be sufficient. And yes, I've never met a programmer who didn't speak his mind to his coworkers :D

Comment: I'll give you back a point if you change your answer to "Whatever *your team* finds to be the most readable"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving snippets, look at the most used [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) using sphinx and compare the doc to the code.

- *[difflib — Helpers for computing deltas](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)*
- *[CPython, file difflib.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/difflib.py)*

The documentation are never out of sync since the annotations sit right inside the code.